# Ajax function to call php function in same pag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My problem is that Ajax in same php file as php function I want to call doesn't work. I want to make that when I press button the page won't reload and the function would be called. I putted my  tag with ajax on the bottom and php function at the top of page if that makes sense. Here's my code :

Ajax :

```
<script>
          function getData() {
              $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "view.php",
                    data: {action: 'PakeistiCashreg'}, 
                    success: function(data){
                        alert('Kasos aparatas sėkmingai pakeistas');
                    }
                  });
                }
          </script>
```

Php function I want to call :

```
if(isset($_GET["action"])) {
   if($_GET["action"] == "PakeistiCashreg") {
      mysql_query("UPDATE ".$table['invoices']." SET `CashReg` = '".$_POST['CashRegInput']."' WHERE `id` = '156' LIMIT 1");
   }
}
```

And the button where action happens :

```
<form method="post"><?php echo CASHREG; ?>:<select name="CashRegInput" id="CashRegInput" class="Input3"><option></option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($CashReg as $key => $value) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select><button name="PakeistiCashreg" onclick="getData();" id="PakeistiCashreg">Pakeisti kasos aparatą</button></form>
```

Comment: have you included jquery in your page as you are using jquery ajax function?   Also please prooooovide some more details like what error are you getting in browser console.

Comment: Also, you might want to tell us what is happening. Like is it reloading the page ? In which case you want to cancel the submit in your getData() call I think.

Comment: @amit wadhwani What do you mean included? I got 404 error code. "XHR Faile loading : Get htttp://........"

Comment: @82Tuskers Page reloads, but data in database doesn't change

Comment: data: {action: 'PakeistiCashreg'},  is the problem i guess, Kindly pass json string,

Comment: This code is insecure. Not only can a malicious user change the value of `CashReg` in the database at will. They can also do SQL injection, because you haven't escaped the user-provided string.

Answer (score 0):

try this : 
Markup:

```
<form name="some-form" method="post" onsubmit="getData(event);">
    <?php echo CASHREG; ?>:
    <select name="CashRegInput" id="CashRegInput" class="Input3">
        <option></option>
        <?php
            foreach($CashReg as $key => $value) {
                echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="PakeistiCashreg" id="PakeistiCashreg">Pakeisti kasos aparatą</button>
</form>
```

script:

```
function getData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cashRegInput = $('#CashRegInput').val();
    if (cashRegInput) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "view.php",
            data: { action: 'PakeistiCashreg', CashRegInput: cashRegInput },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Kasos aparatas sėkmingai pakeistas');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hmmm. Doesn't work. I get this error now Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
    at getData (?mod=invoices&action=view&id=157:200)
    at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit (?mod=invoices&action=view&id=157:110)

Comment: Updated answer. Please check again and advise. Thanks. Also, normally we don't load the handlers in html. But, I have used them as per your code.

Comment: Now I get 500 Internal server error, I think problem is somewhere else

Comment: 500 is a server error. You might need add entries in error_log() and check what the post variables look like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you're saying that you've got a file `view.php` which contains both the page which is originally loaded and the handler for the ajax call. If that's not what you're saying then ignore this answer.

Doing an ajax request is not the same as loading a page. When the client receives the ajax response, all it does is call the appropriate handler. In this case, all it will do is `alert('Kasos aparatas sėkmingai pakeistas');`. It's attempting to run the handler when the page is first loaded, except that you've added a check on `$_GET("action")` which should prevent this. You need a separate URL and a separate handler for the ajax call. For example, you could change the ajax call URL to `action.php`, then move the snippet with the database call into a separate file called `action.php`.

(Actually, PHP is really only intended for returning HTML, not for ajax calls. so it would be better to replace `action.php` with a handler in some other language/framework. But PHP will work, and in any case I don't know enough about your setup to advise on how to do this.)